# Facebook: (#100) Public Comments Blocked

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

We have a Facebook app running for a few months with no problems at all.

Basically, this app writes on a page wall.

We are using the Facebook php SDK.

Today, we start receiving an error: `(#100) Public Comments Blocked`

Couldn't find any info about this error.

Any ideas what's happening here?

Comment: I suddenly started having this problem today too, it's happening when I am posting as the page, using the access token I get using the admins access token.  Everything was working fine until today.  Now many of our posts are getting rejected for this reason.  It is not an issue related to posting too much, I'm manually making the post and it's still not working

Comment: Why did you accept the answer?  It's a useful thought, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm noticing this as well. I believe this is a bug. I filed a bug report. Please add your own steps to the bug to help Facebook fix it.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/310443122312785

Comment: I've subscribed to this bug as well, not sure how I can post reproduction steps though, there doesn't seem to be any options other than subscribe/unsubscribe

Comment: Have you noticed it seems that the bug has been fixed?

Comment: We haven't confirmed it's fixed yet, but it should already be happening far less for most users